# Iterate over serviceproviders in laravel cron

Tags: laravel, eloquent, cron

I have inherited this laravel app and still get accustomed to the framework.

At the moment I try to figure out the "best-practise-way" of iterating through "Service Providers" in a cron job. I have set up the schedule, but I know that just creating an object (or object factory) is probably a big no-no.

How can I get access to an array of all the components in this cron job. something with singeltons probably.

The code:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        
        $some_array = get_all_the_company_components_or_eloquents();

        foreach( $some_array as $company )
        {
            $company->yay("yay");
        }

    })->daily();
}
```

Comment: what "components"? and there is no registry of eloquent models

Comment: sorry, i meant "Service Providers" https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/providers. got mixed up with the terminology.

Comment: what would iterating them do for you?

Comment: let's say you have a database with a bunch of companies. they are mapped to some service, models, controlles, and so on through this laravel framework. now i want to change them in a cron job. i know that all the database actions have to go through the service and model stuff. but how do i get to it.

if this is not possible, i will just query the database directly and be done with it.

Comment: ServiceProviders are not the services themselves ... not sure why you would need to interact with the service providers like this, since they all have already registered and booted what they need to but sure here is a list of them: `app()->getProviders(\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::class)`

Comment: you said: "all have already registered and booted". how do i get them? so they are registered somewhere. is this also true for models?

Comment: you are not going to be able to extract things from these providers ... they are registering bindings with the containers and doing any booting needed (when the framework boots).. they don't return things to you ... you need to read up on the Service Container and what Service Providers are doing to clear this up a lil

Comment: no, there is no way to know what models exist in your project as they are not registered any where, they are just classes you use, they could be anywhere and come from any package etc etc etc .... so if you would like to describe what you are "actually" trying to accomplish that would be great to try and figure it out  :)

Comment: i am not sure how well the previous dev followed the laravel guidelines. i have this thing called a EloquentCompany.php. this cotains a method to disable the compnay. this is done - i guess - via the corresponding model which changes the database. to get all companies there is this method called "all()" that uses "Company::any()->get())" to get all the companies. it is still a mystery how this all plays together and what i am supposed to call at which point. if i get all the companies i would iterate over them all call this disable method on each. thank you very much for your patience

Comment: so you might be getting lost in the abstraction perhaps ... probably supposed to interact with the service and not the models directly if someone wrote something like that, but either way, what ever gets you to the end goal .. but just keep in mind a "service" is just a concept, things aren't that strict

Comment: i know that i am not supposed to use a model directly. i just don't understand the best way to get to the service. so laravel is not so strict about these things? i assumed it was all very much defiend.

Comment: find in the code where it is used, find the class name, see how they are using it ... they could be using a Facade (static proxy), they might be asking the container directly for an instance of it, they might be using dependency injection etc etc .... its not strict in the sense this is your own architecture you have to force yourself to follow, its not the framework